# Error: Failed to lookup view "http://chart.googleapis.com/

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts

I am trying to study nodejs and google charts
I am getting exception 
Error: Failed to lookup view "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:3000,2900,1500&chco=FF0000,0000FF,00FF00&chdl=Foo|Bas|Bar&chds=a&chxt=y&chxl=&chs=300x200&chf=bg,s,00000000"

MY code is as follows

```
if (req.accepts('html')) { //E
           console.log("case of E");
           res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection});

           var Quiche = require('quiche');

           var pie = new Quiche('pie');
           pie.setTransparentBackground(); // Make background transparent
           pie.addData(3000, 'Foo', 'FF0000');
           pie.addData(2900, 'Bas', '0000FF');
           pie.addData(1500, 'Bar', '00FF00');
           var imageUrl = pie.getUrl(false); // First param controls http vs. https
           res.render(imageUrl);

           } else {
           console.log("case of G HIT -------------------");
           res.set('Content-Type','application/json'); //G
           res.send(200, objs); //H
           }
```

What is the reason for the exception 
Error: Failed to lookup view "http://chart.googleapis.com/

Secondly
Is there a better way to show charts in node.js server. I feel i am making a call to http://chart.googleapis.com/ which is not right way to do thinks when i am not connected at home and trying out different apis .

Answer (score 0):

res.render() renders a view, which in most cases maps to an .html file on your server. Since it can't find a view by that name, it is throwing that error. Are you just trying to send some data back? In which case the method I think you're looking for is res.write()

Comment: Sorry i couldnt get . Can you please explain what should be the name of the view ?

Comment: You should take a look at the docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render The name of the view is the name of a file containing html that you want to send back to the client.